# Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found error Solidity

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I want to connect Infura but im getting that error:
`brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network goerli
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageMainProject is the active project.

Error:

```
Running 'scripts\deploy.py::main'...
File "C:\Users\tayyi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\brownie_cli\run.py", line 49, in main
return_value, frame = run(
File "C:\Users\tayyi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 103, in run
return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 23, in main
deploy_simple_storage()
File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 5, in deploy_simple_storage
account = get_account()
File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 19, in get_account
return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
File "C:\Users\tayyi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 140, in add
w3account = web3.eth.account.from_key(private_key)
File "C:\Users\tayyi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\eth_utils\decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\tayyi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\eth_account\account.py", line 250, in from_key
key = self._parsePrivateKey(private_key)
File "C:\Users\tayyi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\eth_utils\decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\tayyi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\eth_account\account.py", line 769, in _parsePrivateKey
return self._keys.PrivateKey(HexBytes(key))
File "C:\Users\tayyi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\hexbytes\main.py", line 23, in new
bytesval = to_bytes(val)
File "C:\Users\tayyi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\hexbytes_utils.py", line 17, in to_bytes
return hexstr_to_bytes(val)
File "C:\Users\tayyi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\hexbytes_utils.py", line 50, in hexstr_to_bytes
return binascii.unhexlify(ascii_hex)
Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with your brownie configuration file or environment file.

**!DON'T PASTE YOUR PRIVATE KEY!**

If you are using the following configuration part in `brownie-config.yaml`

```
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

Please check that you are also using `dotenv` with an `.env` file:

```
dotenv: .env
```

And in `.env` file, you set the following variable with your private key value:

```
PRIVATE_KEY='0xdeadbeefdeadbeef...'
```

Comment: Yes it was about my private key. Thanks you so much :D